# Where can I use OpenMP in my C++ code

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am writing a C++ code to calculate the code coverage and I want to used the OpenMP to help enhance my code by minimizing the overall run time by making the functions work in parallel so I can get less run time.
Can someone please tell me how and where to use the OpenMP?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{



    std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

    char inputFilename[] = "Test-Case-3.cs";   // Test Case File
    char outputFilename[] = "Result.txt"; // Result File

    int totalNumberOfLines = 0;
    int numberOfBranches = 0;
    int statementsCovered = 0;
    float statementCoveragePercentage = 0;
    double overallRuntime = 0;

    ifstream inFile;  // object for reading from a file
    ofstream outFile; // object for writing to a file

    inFile.open(inputFilename, ios::in);
    if (!inFile) {
        cerr << "Can't open input file " << inputFilename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }



    totalNumberOfLines = NoOfLines(inFile);

    inFile.clear();   // reset
    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    numberOfBranches = NoOfBranches(inFile);
    inFile.close();

    statementsCovered = totalNumberOfLines - numberOfBranches;

    statementCoveragePercentage = (float)statementsCovered * 100/ totalNumberOfLines;

    outFile.open(outputFilename, ios::out);

    if (!outFile) {
        cerr << "Can't open output file " << outputFilename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    outFile << "Total Number of Lines" << " : " << totalNumberOfLines << endl;
    outFile << "Number of Branches" << " : " << numberOfBranches << endl;
    outFile << "Statements Covered" << " : " << statementsCovered << endl;
    outFile << "Statement Coverage Percentage" << " : " << statementCoveragePercentage <<"%"<< endl;

    overallRuntime = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    outFile << "Overall Runtime" << " : " << overallRuntime << " Seconds"<< endl;

    outFile.close();

}
```

i want to minimize the time taken to count the number of branches by allowing multiple threads to work in parallel to calculate the number faster? how can i edit the code so that i can use the open mp and here you can find my functions:bool is_only_ascii_whitespace(const std::string& str)
{

```
auto it = str.begin();
do {
    if (it == str.end()) return true;
} while (*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f && std::isspace(*(it++)));
// one of these conditions will be optimized away by the compiler,
// which one depends on whether char is signed or not
return false;
```

}

// Function 1
int NoOfLines(ifstream& inFile)
{

```
//char line[1000];
string line;
int lines = 0;

while (!inFile.eof()) {

    getline(inFile, line);
    //cout << line << endl;

    if ((line.find("//") == std::string::npos))  // Remove Comments
    {
        if (!is_only_ascii_whitespace(line)) // Remove Blank
        {
            lines++;
        }
    } 
    //cout << line << "~" <<endl;
        }    
return lines;
```

}

// Function 2
int NoOfBranches(ifstream& inFile)
{

```
//char line[1000];
string line;
int branches = 0;

while (!inFile.eof()) {

    getline(inFile, line);



    if ((line.find("if") != std::string::npos) || (line.find("else") != std::string::npos))
    {
        branches++;
    }


}   

    return branches;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Which part pf your code is the slow one? I can't see any loops or anything.

Comment: i want to minimize the time taken to count the number of branches by allowing multiple threads to work in parallel to calculate the number faster?

Comment: I don't think using OpenMP will help you at all here. OpenMP isn't magic and doesn't just make everything faster. You need to have an algorithm that can operate in parallel first. The first big obstacle you will need to get past is reading your input one line at a time and processing that line before reading the next one. Not to mention, you are reading the file from disk twice. Unless you have an extremely expensive hard drive, your bottle neck is probably there.

Comment: how can i make it operate in parallel so that  can i can apply the openMp on it

Comment: Why do you want to? You're assuming a solution to your problem and then not being able to implement it. The real problem here is "My code runs too slowly", not "I can't apply OpenMP". So see what @Zack said. Fix the serial problems (read the file once, and in big chunks)...